# Java Spring serialize json to view

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

Looking to output a json object on a JSP view within JAVA Spring. However when I perform the following all I see is the java object toString()

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)                                     
@ResponseBody                                                                                    
public ModelAndView homePage() {                                                                 
    MapDAOImpl mapDAOImpl = (MapDAOImpl) appContext.getBean("mapDAOImpl");                       
    ReturnLocations[] daoResponse  = mapDAOImpl.getPropertiesJsFilter(params);           



    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();                                                     
    model.setViewName("home");                                                                   
    model.addObject("locations", daoResponse);                                                   
    return model;                                                                                
}
```

JSP

```
<script>
<c:out value="${locations}" />
</script>
```

edit solution:

```
 ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();       
 String json = ow.writeValueAsString(daoResponse);                               
 ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();                                        
 model.setViewName("home");                                                      

 model.addObject("locations", json);                                             
 return model;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just serialize the `ReturnLocations[]` to JSON inside your handler method, store the result in a `String` and add that `String` to the `Model`. You'll have access to it in the JSP through request attributes.

An alternative is to render an HTML page with Javascript which sends a request to a separate API which then returns the JSON directly (serialized with `@ResponseBody` for example). You can then do whatever you want with that result.

Comment: That was my initial thought. Wasnt sure if it was the correct approach. As with API calls the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter would serialize the json somehow.

Comment: @user2524908 One alternative is to produce a HTML page with Javascript which sends a request to a different API that retrieves JSON directly.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I also enjoy scala!